# Syntax Error in SQLITE strftime query

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm getting an error when trying to run the following query:

```
 string sql13 = " SELECT  YYMM FROM t2 WHERE strftime(%Y-%m, YYMM)";
```

Error:
near "%": syntax error

Comment: don't you have to compare the result of `strftime(%Y-%m, YYMM)` with some value/field, I am not sure but I guess with `WHERE` you need some kind of comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing the apostrophes around `%Y-%m`. Additionally, you're most likely trying to compare that field to something:

```
string sql13 = "SELECT YYMM FROM t2 WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', YYMM) = '2002-02'";
```

More info on the [`strftime`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).